# How to capture a value from a select in the login view and declare it global?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, materialize, php-7

I cannot manage to capture a value from a combo from my login view, to use it in the user registry. I am trying to use the HTTP routes methods as described in the laravel 5.1 documentation, but without any success.

Here is the combo cboFranquicias in the view of `login.blade.php`, whose value I want to capture to pass it to the user registry view:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="row margin">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
    <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" value="{{ old('usuario') }}" required>
    <label for="usuario" class="center-align">Usuario</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row margin">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="mdi-action-lock-outline prefix"></i>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
      <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
    </div>
  </div>

 <!--COMBO TO LIST FRANQUICIAS -->
   <br><div class="input-field col m12 s12" style="right:-1%">
    {!!Form::select('Franquicias', $combo_franquicias, null, ['placeholder'=>'--Selecciona--','id'=>'cboFranquicias','name'=>'cboFranquicias'])!!} 
    {!!Form::label('Franquicias')!!}
  </div><!--END COMBO -->


  <div class="row">
      <!--ACOMODADO TAMAÑO DEl BOTON ENTRAR-->
    <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12 m12 19">Entrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Later, in routes.php, I declare a route that takes by the method the values entered in the login, to the function that will return the user registry view:

```
Route::get('registrar', 'Auth\AuthController@VistaRegistraUsuario');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@VistaRegistraUsuario');
```

And here is the function that returns to the user registry view in the AuthController.php file:

```
public function VistaRegistraUsuario(Request $request)
  {
 $id_franquicia = $request->input('cboFranquicias');
 //dd($id_franquicia);
 $cargos = cargos_usuarios::lists('descripcion', 'id');

 return view('auth.register', compact('cargos','id_franquicia'));
  }
```

However, the value never reaches the user registry view, which should pass to fill my hidden input in that view register.blade.php:

```
{!!Form::input('Id_franquicia', $id_franquicia, null, 
['type'=>'hidden','name'=>'id_franquicia', 'id'=>'id_franquicia'])!!}
```

How do I capture the value of the `franquicias` combo in the login view and save it to a global variable, to pass that value to the user registration view?

Comment: why aren't you use session??

Comment: there isn't any option in the select (dropdown) ?

Comment: the values of the selects are charged from database. But that is not the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the session method, thus leaving the solution:

Right after submitting for the login, I captured the selected value of my franquicia combo:

```
  `protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::user());
    }

    $id_franquicia = $request->input('franquicia_id');//CAPTURO LA ID DEL COMBO DE FRANQUICIAS
    Session::set('id_franquicia', $id_franquicia);// GUARDO EN UNA VARIABLE GLOBAL LA ID CAPTURADA, POR MEDIO DE SESSION

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());


}`
```

I capture the value of the id with request->input, and I save it in a variable that I then declare global with session :: set, to then use it in my user registration view with session :: get

```
//VISTA PARA EL REGISTRO DE USUARIO
  public function VistaRegistraUsuario()
{

  $id_franquicia_usuario = Session::get('id_franquicia');//ID DE LA FRANQUICIA
  $cargos = cargos_usuarios::lists('descripcion', 'id'); //COMBO DE LOS CARGOS

  return view('auth.register', compact('cargos', 'id_franquicia_usuario'));
}// FIN VISTA
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your select reference, the first parameter to the `Form::select` method is the name of the field. So try,

```
{!!Form::select('cboFranquicias', $combo_franquicias, null, ['placeholder'=>'--Selecciona--','id'=>'cboFranquicias'])!!}
```

In your Controller you are using `$request->input('cboFranquicias')`

So no need to pass the `name` as part of the options, from the [method signature](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/99342cc22507cf8d7178bb390c215968183993bb/src/FormBuilder.php#L520) if the `options['name']` is not set it will default to the `$name`

**Update to use session logic**

You could do something like the following if you want to keep the same endpoint for a post after login and then a get to the same endpoint:

```
public function VistaRegistraUsuario(Request $request)
{
    // Set the session on the auth/login post request
    if ($request->has('cboFranquicias')) {
        session(['id_franquicia' => $request->input('cboFranquicias')]);
    }

    $cargos = cargos_usuarios::lists('descripcion', 'id');

    return view('auth.register', [
        'cargos' => $cargos,
        'id_franquicia' => session('id_franquicia'),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Good advice, you're right. It happens that the value of the franquicia combo that I capture from login, is shown with dd ($ id_franquicia); just after the login, but since entering the main view the value is no longer displayed and becomes null, much less is displayed in the user registration view where I really want to use that value.

Comment: I presume the value is correct inside the ```auth.register``` view directly after ```auth.login```. But on a subsequent get request the value will be gone. To have it available you would need to use ```sessions```. (I added an update for session logic). The workflow might also be clearer if you use different endpoint actions for post and get.